# Postgresql & django Error- Connection refused tIs the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have been struggling at this problem for several days.

Previousy, I have compiler source code from OpenPLM and running successfully in Debian 6. However, I observed some Alert Mails could not be send out recently.

I checked the log and find some error as below. It seems that the connection to PostgreSQL was not successful. I googled it and tried to find solution by setting below, but it still did not work.

I am wondering if any one can help me to find the problem. Any advice and suggestion is highly appreciated.

- System Configuration

  1. sourcecode: http://www.openplm.org/docs/2.0/en/admin/ht_1_install_server.htm
  2. OS: Debian 6 32 bit
  3. PostgreSQL: 9.1
  4. firewall is off
  5. port 5432 is on.

  enter

  A. postgresql.conf 
     listen_addresses = '*'
     port = 5432

  B. pg_hba.conf

  local   all             all                                     md5

  host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5

  host    all             all              ::/0                            md5

---

====================Error Message====================

```
root@openplm:/var/log/celery# cat w1.log
[2017-08-01 16:06:22,702: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 390, in start
    self.consume_messages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 474, in consume_messages
    readers[fileno](fileno, event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 292, in drain_nowait
    self.drain_events(timeout=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/librabbitmq/__init__.py", line 220, in drain_events
    self._basic_recv(timeout)
ConnectionError: server connection error 320 message: CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown'
[2017-08-01 16:06:23,122: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://openplm@localhost:5672/openplm: Error opening socket: a socket error occurred.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...

[2017-08-01 16:06:25,176: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://openplm@localhost:5672/openplm: Error opening socket: a socket error occurred.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...

[2017-08-01 16:06:29,228: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://openplm@localhost:5672/openplm: Error opening socket: a socket error occurred.
Trying again in 6.00 seconds...

[2017-08-01 16:09:13,046: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/loaders.py:132: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn("Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never "

[2017-08-01 16:09:13,089: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@w1.openplm ready.
[2017-08-01 16:09:13,291: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to amqp://openplm@localhost:5672/openplm.
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,655: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[531a147d-bd63-4891-b004-990d6aa3a3e5]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,673: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[09b7b067-2ab2-42a4-b159-665d4876655e]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,674: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[12710566-6809-424f-91a0-4b874738ab3e]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,675: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[317fc84f-244a-400b-ae35-154f9c41eef3]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,691: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[f27a4e93-cb7b-43df-8a6c-8066cd5ad38b]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,701: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[526f48de-7b16-4cc2-b71e-14b57f05029c]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,703: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[0d63986d-3c75-4306-a3fe-ea282b3d55d6]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,725: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[4e447b6a-a624-44b1-aa87-3d564f68fc55]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,726: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[5354a951-8788-49ac-98f1-482ca107dce2]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,802: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[f6c886b8-e55c-4690-8fc9-7ad958ce03d7]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,803: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[a5430277-9415-465b-975c-cb06f642de4c]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,823: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[0f1035e5-98ca-458b-8d39-f48ab2c6eb17]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,824: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[02873411-b9f3-4205-96e9-812c32777d83]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,826: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[9030f0c9-03f1-47a3-884e-880ee77fba2d]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,827: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[01dc6178-f468-4cb8-b042-1c74b5e7fe11]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,879: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[b747bd56-60ff-4060-a358-6d302fcfc16a]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,969: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[765e40bb-abf4-49dd-833d-808cd0d19b58]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,970: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[3694e18c-d1f0-4f1c-b57a-4aeeb8a58ed7]
[2017-08-01 16:09:23,970: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[77eb658d-feda-4213-bd47-da1aa4cc0656]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,028: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[d0883af8-cf65-400b-9690-c8177c024b0c]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,030: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[844ca035-ac57-4740-9b3a-20a1d1c7e04d]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,031: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[45bac374-84a6-4f68-88f8-b5af0cc28968]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,130: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[7e6d2d67-b8a3-4546-8077-8573208f69d4]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,180: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[20b483af-0fc5-471b-8b1f-8c4f151e59cd]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,181: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[d3ffca3c-f229-4162-b201-52445609e64d]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,182: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[3fd60f2f-c99c-4aa9-a645-c1a9f954183f]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,182: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[8bbefc40-6395-439b-b476-7f2408881e50]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,183: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[cf8a7d22-90c1-4900-bcc4-9efbb99d48b5]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,257: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[3c9167a2-5ce4-4788-9a9e-a90e9cd0ccd4]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,258: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[24f84d43-a635-4598-b452-5fb58c7cba96]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,258: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[6562778e-ac71-4d51-8505-c36e1faf5555]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,259: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[45bc8b70-8709-4ddc-af95-d0d72419fb99]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,305: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.mail.do_send_histories_mail[a1e95ce4-a718-420e-83bc-0d9bc3356d3f]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,306: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[fd940fc4-c977-49fd-aed9-b0cf383808f7]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,335: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.mail.do_send_histories_mail[c84f099d-ef4e-4e00-93c5-98f01c6ff909]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,337: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.mail.do_send_histories_mail[4f46f83b-07f2-4591-b343-77a6b0731c11]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,338: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[669cb21d-3d5f-425f-be59-4b5878df1fe4]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,339: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.mail.do_send_histories_mail[3fa618e4-a04b-4fff-8257-55fba6deab6b]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,391: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.mail.do_send_histories_mail[6eddbd62-d801-4649-9259-c5bb88c3b0e8]
[2017-08-01 16:09:24,411: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: openPLM.plmapp.tasks.update_index[9b873cb0-0703-4259-bf38-d1699a606ef8]
[2017-08-01 16:09:27,288: WARNING/PoolWorker-3] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/task/trace.py:328: RuntimeWarning: Exception raised outside body: OperationalError('could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\ncould not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (10.0.2.15) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n',):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 237, in trace_task
    R = I.handle_error_state(task, eager=eager)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 104, in handle_error_state
    }[self.state](task, store_errors=store_errors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 130, in handle_failure
    task.backend.mark_as_failure(req.id, exc, einfo.traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 113, in mark_as_failure
    traceback=traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 257, in store_result
    self._store_result(task_id, result, status, traceback, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/backends/database.py", line 27, in _store_result
    traceback=traceback, children=self.current_task_children())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 41, in _inner
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 174, in store_result
    "meta": {"children": children}})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 83, in update_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().update_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 67, in update_or_create
    obj, created = self.get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 484, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 398, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 106, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 317, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 775, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 839, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 324, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 182, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (10.0.2.15) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?


  exc, exc_info.traceback)))
 here
```

Comment: This question requires serious formatting.

Comment: Yes, I have edit it with better formation. Sorry for the inconvenience.